# Definition of a "Surface" -- an open ball or an open subset of $R^2$?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, surfaces

I have learnt that **surface** is a topological space such that every point has a neighborhood which is homeomorphic to an **open subset** of the Euclidean plane $R^2$. --- *(a)*

But then, it seems that people use another definition that "a surface is ... that has a neighborhood homeomorphic to an **open ball** in $R^2$". --- *(b)*

Clearly, *(b)* implies *(a)*, but does *(a)* also imply *(b)*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does. Let $p$ be the point on the surface and $\varphi$ the homeomorphism. The open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ contains an open ball around each point by definition. Take an open ball around $\varphi(p)$. This ball is homeomorphic to an open neighborhood of $p$ via $\varphi^{-1}$ restricted to the ball.